# What is the purpose of View.hasTransientState()

Tags: android

Specifically [`setHasTransientState(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setHasTransientState(boolean)). **How** and **why** would one use it? I'm looking for a "real life" scenario.

The docs definition:

> Set whether this view is currently tracking transient state that the framework should attempt to preserve when possible. This flag is reference counted, so every call to setHasTransientState(true) should be paired with a later call to setHasTransientState(false).
>   A view with transient state cannot be trivially rebound from an external data source, such as an adapter binding item views in a list. This may be because the view is performing an animation, tracking user selection of content, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If the view is listview item, setHasTransientState can prevent it from recycling.If it is in animation, it is userful. Transient is just a special state of view, I think it means dont touch me(as recycle),and I will become not transient soon.

Comment: Thanks. But you don't set `setHasTransientState` manually whenever you animate a view in a list (I assume it is done for you). I wonder when do you as a dev actually have to set this state manually.

Comment: U can watch the code of ViewPropertyAnimator,and you will find "mView.setHasTransientState(true);" in startAnimation,and "mView.setHasTransientState(false);" in onAnimationEnd

Comment: You should use it if you use for example ObjectAnimator, or any other kind of custom animation. In this case, view CAN be reused while the animation is not finished yet. To prevent it you should set "setHasTransientState" to "true" at the beginning of animation and set it to "false" when animation finished